# Build formula without doing symlinks

Tags: homebrew

I need to install a modified version of a formula (MPI version of `hdf5` by adding options that are no longer supported).

Now the problem is that I do not want to symlink this library in the `/usr/local/`... tree, but would just like to compile and keep it aside in a `/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5` directory.

Is it possible?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/563484/95929.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you just need to add

`keg_only "it conflicts with other hdf5 libraries"`

to the ruby formula